# three level system and holonomies

Tags: berry-pancharatnam-phase

I'm doing an excercise from the book "Introduction to Topological Quantum Computation" of J. Pachos. This is excercise 2.1 related to the berry phase.

The problem asks to consider the following hamiltonian

$$H =\begin{bmatrix}
    \Delta & \Omega_1 & \Omega_2  \\
    \Omega_1^{*} & 0 & 0  \\
    \Omega_2^* & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

Where $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are complex numbers and $\Delta$ is a real shift. It is asked to evaluate all the possible holonomies that can be produced by manipulating $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$. As a hint it is first recommended that the degeneration condition is determined.

**Attempt at solution:**

I'm actually rather los with the excercise so any help is appreciated.I first tried to determine de degeneration condition. The problem is I arrive to the following eigen values: $\lambda_0 = 0$, $\lambda_{\pm} = \frac{\Delta \pm  \sqrt{\Delta^2 + 4 A} }{2}$. Where $A=\Omega_1^2 + \Omega_2^2$. The degeneration condition I obtain is $\Omega_1 = \Omega_2 = 0$. This result is obtained by imposing $\lambda_{-}=0$.

Now i'm rather confused with the expression calculating the "holonomies". Does this mean I should calculate the gauge potentials? What is exactly that i'm asked to calculate?

Comment: I suspect that by "holonomy" they mean $\mathcal{P}\exp(i\oint A dx)$, the path ordered integral that gives the Wilson loop (with $A$ the Berry connection). What is the space through which the $\Omega_j$ can vary? Where they're degenerate, there's a singularity in the Berry curvature. You'll probably find that you can get different holonomies by choosing the integration contour to surround or not surround these degeneracies.

Comment: How could in this context construct the holonomy to calculate it?